# how to sent json value to module?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i responsed json object from api and i tried to send the response to the module using setter then to the Recyclerview adapter but its not working

This is my fragment

```
public class ListViewActivityFragment extends Fragment {
List<AppShowModule> appShowModule;
RecyclerView AppRecyclerView;

RecyclerView.LayoutManager AppRecyclerViewlayoutManager;
RecyclerView.Adapter AppRecyclerViewadapter;
String jsonUrl = "https://itunes.apple.com/jo/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=50/json";
TextView text;
Context context;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
public ListViewActivityFragment() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_view, container, false);
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    appShowModule = new ArrayList<>();
    AppRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById( R.id.AppRecyclerView );


    AppRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize( true );
    AppRecyclerView.setLayoutManager( AppRecyclerViewlayoutManager );
    JsonAppShowData();}
public void JsonAppShowData() {

    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( jsonUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray( "entry" );
                AppShowModule appShowModule111 = new AppShowModule();

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject( i ).getJSONObject("im:name");
                    String name = response.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray("entry").getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("im:name").getString("label").toString();
                    appShowModule111.setAppName(name);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e( "LOG", error.toString() );
        }
    } );
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue( getContext() );
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    AppRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    AppRecyclerViewadapter = new ListViewAdapter(appShowModule,getContext() );
    AppRecyclerView.setAdapter(AppRecyclerViewadapter);
}
```

}

And this is my adapter

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;

List<AppShowModule> getDataAdapter;


public ListViewAdapter(List<AppShowModule> getDataAdapter, Context context){

    super();

    this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.appitem, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

    return viewHolder;
}



@Override


public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position)

{


    final AppShowModule getDataAdapter1 = getDataAdapter.get( position );

    holder.NameTextView.setText( getDataAdapter1.getAppName() );

    Picasso.with( context ).load( getDataAdapter1.getAppImageUrl() ).into( holder.imgPost );


}




@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return getDataAdapter.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView NameTextView;
    public ImageView imgPost;
    LinearLayout lnrLayout;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);


        NameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.appName);
        imgPost = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.appImage);
        lnrLayout = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lnrLayout);





    }


}
}
```

And this is my module

```
  public class AppShowModule
  {
     private String appName;
  private String appImageUrl;



  public String getAppName() {
    return appName;}
  public void setAppName(String appName) {
      this.appName = appName;}
  public String getAppImageUrl() {
      return appImageUrl;}
public void setAppImageUrl(String appImageUrl) {
      this.appImageUrl = appImageUrl;}
  }
```

Comment: does your recyclerview get visible when you get the data from the network call ?

Comment: no nothing to show just this error in logcat

Comment: try one thing, initially create empty arraylist of `AppShowModule` and set the adapter, then whenever your network call finishes, then just fill the data in that array list and call `notifydatasetchanged`, see if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not initialize your adapter when you get a response from the web service. Do it on activity create and when you get your data, update the adapter.

Comment: i do it and i got this error 
09-04 15:09:02.295 20601-20601/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
09-04 15:09:02.295 20601-20601/? E/EnterpriseKnoxManager: Failed at EnterpriseContainerManager API getEnterpriseContainerManager 
                                                          java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: Container with Id 1 does not exists

Comment: This is related to your webservice call. Not the adapter I think. Try to disable the webservice and put dummy data in the adapter.